# VS 2010 - I need extension for editing LESS stylesheets

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stylesheet, less

I'm using LessExtension from B.S.Nissen in VS 2010. Works good, but on big *.less files ("big" in this case is more than 100 (hundred) lines) works **very** slow.
Who knows more quick and performant plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench has worked very well for me and seems to have a lot of momentum in the community as well

Comment: I know about Web Workbench, but it doesn't compile LESS files in free edition. And this huge license rectangle in right bottom corner...